# Mongoose does not return _id in findOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

To get better storage and to use UUID's as the primary key, I customize the default functionality for _id to store as a UUID as a binary bson type 4. I then setup a virtual for id to return the value of _id.

Here is an example schema using ES6 as described:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require('mongoose-uuid2')(mongoose);
const UUID = mongoose.Types.UUID;
const uuid = require('node-uuid');
const bson = require('bson');

const schema_options = { 
    id: false,
    getters: true,
    virtuals: true,
    toObject: {
        versionKey: false,
        transform: function (doc, ret) {
            delete ret.__v;
            //delete ret._id;
        }
},
    toJSON: {
        versionKey: false,
        transform: function (doc, ret) {
          //delete ret._id;
          delete ret.__v
        }
      }  
};

const BaseSchema = new Schema (
    {
        _id: { type: UUID, default: uuid.v4, required: true },
        code: { type: String },
        name: { type: String },
        timestamps: { 
            created: {type: Date, required: true},
            updated: {type: Date, required: true}
        },
        __v: { type: Number, select: false}
    }, schema_options
);

class BaseSchemaClass {

    //virtuals
    get id() {
        return this._id;
    }

    set id(uuid_string){

        console.log(uuid_string);
        let uuid_parse = uuid.parse(uuid_string);
        console.log(uuid_parse);
        let id_buffer = new mongoose.Types.Buffer(uuid_parse);
        id_buffer.subtype(bson.Binary.SUBTYPE_UUID);
        console.log(id_buffer);
        this._id = id_buffer.toObject();
    }

    //private
    static convert_uuid_string_to_buffer (uuid_string) {

        var uuid_parse = uuid.parse(uuid_string);
        var id = new db.Types.Buffer(uuid_parse);
        id.subtype(bson.Binary.SUBTYPE_UUID);
        return id.toObject();
    }
}

BaseSchema.loadClass(BaseSchemaClass);
module.exports = BaseSchema;
```

The schema data appears to update and you can read the data as expected. In addition, it appears that saves to the database occur as expected as well.

Here is an example record:

```
{ "_id" : BinData(4,"yyfw80jURj+35wguKCKJRg=="), "timestamps" : { "updated" : ISODate("2018-01-28T19:47:05.825Z"), "created" : ISODate("2018-01-28T19:47:05.825Z") }, "code" : "MAR", "name" : "Michael", "__v" : 0 }
```

However, when using mongoose to find a record, using a non "_id" field, the "_id" field does not return. The virtual retreives the _id and it is undefined.

Here is an example in using the schema.

```
const BaseSchema = require('./schemas/base');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.Promise = require("bluebird");

let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {

    const BaseModel = mongoose.model('Base', BaseSchema);

    let base_document = new BaseModel({code: "MAR", name: "Michael", timestamps :{updated: new Date(), created: new Date() }});
    console.log(base_document.id)
    console.log(base_document.code)
    base_document.save()
    .then(() => {
      return Promise.resolve();  
    })
    .then(() => {

        return BaseModel.findOne({code: "MAR"}).exec();
    })
    .then((record) => {
        //fails
        console.log(record.id)
        console.log(record.code)
        console.log(record);
        return BaseModel.findByIdAndUpdate(record.id, { $set: { name: 'Steve', code: "STV" }});
    })
    .then(() => {

        return BaseModel.findOne({name: "Steve"}).exec();
    })
    .then((record) => {
        //fails
        console.log(record.id);
        console.log(record.code);
        console.log(record);
        db.close();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

I am at a loss on why the _id is not returning in the schema, I have tried variations of find and find an update of the above but it still does not return the _id. I need some assistance in determining the problem.

Here is the versions of npm packages I am using

```
"bluebird": "^3.5.1",
"bson": "^1.0.4",
"mongoose": "^5.0.1",
"mongoose-uuid2": "^2.0.2",
"node-uuid": "^1.4.8"
```

I have tried using node 9.2.0 and 8.9.4 with the same result.

I am also using mongo 3.2

Comment: Probably `_id` instead of `id`?

Comment: @oneturkmen as mentioned in the message. I setup id as a virtual which returns _id. I can see that id getter is getting called but _id is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some guidance and assistance from @serge, I was able to find an alternative solution. Basically the mongoose-uuid2 (https://github.com/niahmiah/mongoose-uuid) package only supports update mongoose 4 due to version 5 supporting new ES6 constructs and in addition, it only supports bson 0.4 due to changes that were introduced in the bson contract on version 1.0. For backwards compatibility, I understand why this is this way.

I ended up having to create a fork of mongoose-uuid2, https://github.com/thxmike/mongoose-uuid which uses the new bson contract and new mongoose api's.

I have placed a pull request but for backwards compatibility, this may fail.
I am not sure if and how the author wants to address this concern.
https://github.com/niahmiah/mongoose-uuid/pull/11

Edit:
@serge: Has addressed this in the main repo now works with Mongoose 5.
https://github.com/niahmiah/mongoose-uuid. Awesome

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mongoose-uuid2` depends on `mongoose 4.x`, but you have `^5.0.1` in your package dependencies.

This configuration makes your package manager install two different versions of mongoose with their dependencies: 5.x for your code and 4.x for `mongoose-uuid2`.

So, when it comes to cast binary value of `_id` field to `UUID` schema type, this condition at `mongoose-uuid2/index.js:101` evaluates to false:

```
if (value instanceof mongoose.Types.Buffer.Binary)
  return value;
```

That's because `mongoose.Types.Buffer.Binary` in 4.x and 5.x versions are different from the node's point of view. Even if they use exactly the same versions of `mongodb` and `bson` packages.

Finally, it throws `"Could not cast _id to uuid."` error and mongoose doesn't include `_id` field in the document.